# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I was working on Eclipse RCP 
and I got this error

---

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fef54b88ee, pid=3192, tid=5324

JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [jscript9.dll+0x888ee]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
 F:\Eclipse RCP\hs_err_pid3192.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Comment: Any info on this? I am having a very similar problem while trying to run Unit Tests.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this was likely caused by Windows UAC, see [java.com's description](https://java.com/en/download/help/exception_access.xml).

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't accept any answer yet, one of the possible cause of this error is to have some class with **main** constructor where that class is not the default activity. To solve the problem:

1. Run configuration.
2. in the tree of lunch configuration, remove that class from **java application** if listed. (but keep the **android application** listed in the tree of lunch applications)