# Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, javac, minidump

I'm trying to connect to an application written in VB using Jintegra to access it from JAVA. Since I don't know how to work on JINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE from Eclipse, I'm forced to use cmd and Javac... Anyways, I get this irritating error everytime I try to run the link (No actual code, just the link to the other application. I read all other related questions here and couldnt get anything that might help..
I'm totally novice about this..
Please If you can help, gimme a hand here.. Here is the whole Error:

```
 #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fee9da3d6f, pid=8628, tid=0x00000000000025c0
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ntvinv.dll+0x13d6f]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000000038d800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9664, stack(0x0000000002540000,0x0000000002640000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000022bf828, RCX=0x0000000000000d80, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000000263f020, RBP=0x000000000263f310, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x00000000022bf830
R8 =0x0000000000000052, R9 =0x00000000d7aadc10, R10=0x0000000000000008, R11=0x00000000705ec358
R12=0x000000000038d9f8, R13=0x0000000000451e70, R14=0x0000000000000010, R15=0x000000000000001d
RIP=0x000007fee9da3d6f, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000263f020)
0x000000000263f020:   00000000022bf828 000000000263f310
0x000000000263f030:   0000000000000000 00000000022bf828
0x000000000263f040:   0000000000451e70 000000013f4a0a10
0x000000000263f050:   0000000000451e80 0000000070016101
0x000000000263f060:   0000000000000000 00000000022bf830
0x000000000263f070:   800706f400000004 0000000000451e70
0x000000000263f080:   000000000263f340 00000000022bf828
0x000000000263f090:   000000000263f360 000000000038d9f8
0x000000000263f0a0:   000000000263f338 0000000000000001
0x000000000263f0b0:   0000000000000001 000000000263f0e0
0x000000000263f0c0:   000000001719b3c8 0000000080802048
0x000000000263f0d0:   fffffffffffffffe 00000000028d0b80
0x000000000263f0e0:   45a3bb79e17126b0 0daa44d6352982bd
0x000000000263f0f0:   0000000000000001 000000000278d4dc
0x000000000263f100:   000000013f3f07a8 0000000000000001
0x000000000263f110:   000000000263f190 000000000264835d 

Instructions: (pc=0x000007fee9da3d6f)
0x000007fee9da3d4f:   4c 8b c8 e9 e4 02 00 00 83 f8 04 74 0e 83 f8 05
0x000007fee9da3d5f:   74 09 83 f8 03 0f 85 55 03 00 00 49 8b 44 f5 00
0x000007fee9da3d6f:   48 8b 08 48 85 c9 0f 84 44 03 00 00 48 8b 01 ff
0x000007fee9da3d7f:   50 10 e9 39 03 00 00 49 8b 44 f5 00 48 8b 08 41 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00000000022bf828 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000d80 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000000263f020 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000038d800
RBP=0x000000000263f310 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000000000038d800
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000022bf830 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000052 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00000000d7aadc10 is an oop
com.linar.jintegra.Param 
 - klass: 'com/linar/jintegra/Param'
R10=0x0000000000000008 is an unknown value
R11=0x00000000705ec358 is an unknown value
R12=0x000000000038d9f8 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000451e70 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
R15=0x000000000000001d is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000002540000,0x0000000002640000],  sp=0x000000000263f020,  free space=1020k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [ntvinv.dll+0x13d6f]
C  0x0000000002657f54

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.linar.jintegra.NativeObjRef.nativeVtblInvoke(Lcom/linar/jintegra/Rpc;[BLjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;[Lcom/linar/jintegra/Param;[Ljava/lang/Object;I)V+0
j  com.linar.jintegra.NativeObjRef.a(Lcom/linar/jintegra/Rpc;Lcom/linar/jintegra/Uuid;Lcom/linar/jintegra/AuthInfo;)V+82
j  com.linar.jintegra.Dispatch.vtblInvoke(Ljava/lang/String;I[Ljava/lang/Object;)V+106
j  hysys._SimulationCase20Proxy.getFlowsheet()Lhysys/Flowsheet;+24
j  hysys.SimulationCase.getFlowsheet()Lhysys/Flowsheet;+4
j  Code1.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+50
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000001ab3f800 JavaThread "J-Integra COM initialization thread (please don't touch)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10060, stack(0x000000001b7e0000,0x000000001b8e0000)]
  0x000000001a97e800 JavaThread "Thread-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9776, stack(0x000000001b0a0000,0x000000001b1a0000)]
  0x0000000018c13000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10172, stack(0x0000000019a80000,0x0000000019b80000)]
  0x0000000018bcb800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9856, stack(0x000000001a4d0000,0x000000001a5d0000)]
  0x0000000018bb1000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9424, stack(0x000000001a5d0000,0x000000001a6d0000)]
  0x0000000018b99800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10160, stack(0x000000001a330000,0x000000001a430000)]
  0x0000000018b91000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10164, stack(0x000000001a0a0000,0x000000001a1a0000)]
  0x0000000018b8d800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9004, stack(0x000000001a1d0000,0x000000001a2d0000)]
  0x0000000018b8c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10148, stack(0x0000000019cb0000,0x0000000019db0000)]
  0x00000000179bd000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6544, stack(0x0000000019f40000,0x000000001a040000)]
  0x0000000018b33800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9580, stack(0x0000000019df0000,0x0000000019ef0000)]
=>0x000000000038d800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9664, stack(0x0000000002540000,0x0000000002640000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000018b30800 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000019ba0000,0x0000000019ca0000] [id=10180]
  0x0000000018c6f000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000001a770000,0x000000001a870000] [id=6628]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 13269K [0x00000000d5800000, 0x00000000da300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 24% used [0x00000000d5800000,0x00000000d5ffbf48,0x00000000d7880000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d7880000,0x00000000d7d79700,0x00000000d7d80000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d9e00000,0x00000000d9e00000,0x00000000da300000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 4755K [0x0000000080800000, 0x0000000085d80000, 0x00000000d5800000)
  object space 87552K, 5% used [0x0000000080800000,0x0000000080ca4e28,0x0000000085d80000)
 Metaspace       used 7980K, capacity 8146K, committed 8448K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 880K, capacity 923K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000011a00000,0x0000000011e00000] byte_map_base: 0x00000000115fc000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000705fa6d0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012c10000, 0x0000000014bf0000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014bf0000, 0x0000000016bd0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000130000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=3029Kb max_used=3042Kb free=242730Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002640000, 0x0000000002940000, 0x0000000011640000]
 total_blobs=1043 nmethods=705 adapters=251
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 2.077 Thread 0x0000000018b99800  701       4       java.lang.Integer::parseInt (7 bytes)
Event: 2.078 Thread 0x0000000018b91000  702       4       sun.net.www.ParseUtil::encodePath (336 bytes)
Event: 2.078 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800  703       3       sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Decoder::decodeLoop (28 bytes)
Event: 2.079 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800 nmethod 703 0x000000000292d650 code [0x000000000292d7e0, 0x000000000292dd18]
Event: 2.081 Thread 0x0000000018b99800 nmethod 701 0x000000000292cb50 code [0x000000000292cca0, 0x000000000292d138]
Event: 2.084 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800  705       3       java.lang.Exception::<init> (6 bytes)
Event: 2.084 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800 nmethod 705 0x0000000002937490 code [0x0000000002937620, 0x0000000002937c08]
Event: 2.084 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800  706       3       java.lang.Class::searchMethods (90 bytes)
Event: 2.085 Thread 0x0000000018bcb800 nmethod 706 0x0000000002935bd0 code [0x0000000002935e20, 0x0000000002936d98]
Event: 2.087 Thread 0x0000000018b91000 nmethod 702 0x000000000293b310 code [0x000000000293b4a0, 0x000000000293bd68]

GC Heap History (2 events):
Event: 2.008 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 33280K [0x00000000d5800000, 0x00000000d8280000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 100% used [0x00000000d5800000,0x00000000d7880000,0x00000000d7880000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d7d80000,0x00000000d8280000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d7880000,0x00000000d7880000,0x00000000d7d80000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 0K [0x0000000080800000, 0x0000000085d80000, 0x00000000d5800000)
  object space 87552K, 0% used [0x0000000080800000,0x0000000080800000,0x0000000085d80000)
 Metaspace       used 7761K, capacity 7890K, committed 8192K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 854K, capacity 923K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 2.043 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=1 (full 0):
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 5093K [0x00000000d5800000, 0x00000000da300000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 33280K, 0% used [0x00000000d5800000,0x00000000d5800000,0x00000000d7880000)
  from space 5120K, 99% used [0x00000000d7880000,0x00000000d7d79700,0x00000000d7d80000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000000d9e00000,0x00000000d9e00000,0x00000000da300000)
 ParOldGen       total 87552K, used 4755K [0x0000000080800000, 0x0000000085d80000, 0x00000000d5800000)
  object space 87552K, 5% used [0x0000000080800000,0x0000000080ca4e28,0x0000000085d80000)
 Metaspace       used 7761K, capacity 7890K, committed 8192K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 854K, capacity 923K, committed 1024K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (1 events):
Event: 0.131 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000027a14b8 method=java.lang.String.<init>([CII)V @ 18

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.021 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5807cc0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\sy,・・?
Event: 0.021 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d5807fa8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\{ZS.ｹ?
Event: 0.099 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5a3dd80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.099 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5a3df90) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.100 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5a41e78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.100 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d5a42088) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.132 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': <clinit>> (0x00000000d5bb2c80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 1613]
Event: 0.196 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d5dbaf20) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.197 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000d5dc8690) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 0.213 Thread 0x000000000038d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': <clinit>> (0x00000000d5e56820) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u101\7261\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 1613]

Events (10 events):
Event: 2.080 loading class I
Event: 2.080 loading class I done
Event: 2.081 loading class hysys/SafetyAnalysisManager
Event: 2.081 loading class hysys/SafetyAnalysisManager done
Event: 2.081 loading class hysys/SafetyAnalysisManagerProxy
Event: 2.081 loading class hysys/SafetyAnalysisManagerProxy done
Event: 2.082 loading class hysys/Attachments
Event: 2.082 loading class hysys/Attachments done
Event: 2.083 loading class hysys/AttachmentsProxy
Event: 2.083 loading class hysys/AttachmentsProxy done


Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f3a0000 - 0x000000013f3d7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe
0x0000000077780000 - 0x000000007792a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077560000 - 0x000000007767f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd5d0000 - 0x000007fefd63a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00000000751b0000 - 0x0000000075239000     C:\Windows\System32\SYSFER.DLL
0x000007feff3f0000 - 0x000007feff4cb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefeeb0000 - 0x000007fefef4f000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe8e0000 - 0x000007fefe8ff000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007feff960000 - 0x000007feffa8d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000077680000 - 0x000000007777a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007feff580000 - 0x000007feff5e7000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007feff4d0000 - 0x000007feff4de000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007fefe900000 - 0x000007fefe9ca000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefc080000 - 0x000007fefc274000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_fa3b1e3d17594757\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007fefe9d0000 - 0x000007fefea41000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefe6a0000 - 0x000007fefe6ce000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefefb0000 - 0x000007feff0b9000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x0000000050320000 - 0x00000000503f2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x000000006fde0000 - 0x000000007067a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007fef8ac0000 - 0x000007fef8ac9000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007feff0c0000 - 0x000007feff10d000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007feff5f0000 - 0x000007feff5f8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefb1f0000 - 0x000007fefb22b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007fefc570000 - 0x000007fefc57c000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x0000000077950000 - 0x0000000077957000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006a700000 - 0x000000006a70f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00000000504e0000 - 0x0000000050509000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.dll
0x000000006a6e0000 - 0x000000006a6f6000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000007fefd870000 - 0x000007fefe5fc000     C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007fefe6d0000 - 0x000007fefe8d3000     C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x000007fefd4c0000 - 0x000007fefd4cf000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000000005fe80000 - 0x000000005fe9a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefcc50000 - 0x000007fefcca5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefcc40000 - 0x000007fefcc47000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefb4c0000 - 0x000007fefb4d5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fefa4f0000 - 0x000007fefa505000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fefa510000 - 0x000007fefa529000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefcad0000 - 0x000007fefcb2b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fefa4e0000 - 0x000007fefa4eb000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fefa4d0000 - 0x000007fefa4e0000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x000007fefc640000 - 0x000007fefc647000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fefb0e0000 - 0x000007fefb107000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x000007fefb180000 - 0x000007fefb18b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefa5d0000 - 0x000007fefa5d8000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefb120000 - 0x000007fefb173000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000007fee9d90000 - 0x000007fee9de0000     C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\bin\ntvinv.dll
0x000007feff7e0000 - 0x000007feff8ba000     C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x000007fefa360000 - 0x000007fefa367000     C:\Windows\system32\mtxex.dll
0x000007fef44f0000 - 0x000007fef46a0000     C:\Windows\system32\COMSVCS.DLL
0x000007fefd350000 - 0x000007fefd35f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefa950000 - 0x000007fefa959000     C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\bin\International\ntvinvenglishresourcedll.dll
0x0000000078e60000 - 0x00000000793bd000     C:\Windows\system32\mfc100.dll
0x000007fefa160000 - 0x000007fefa167000     C:\Windows\system32\MSIMG32.dll
0x000007fefc020000 - 0x000007fefc076000     C:\Windows\system32\UxTheme.dll
0x000007fefb030000 - 0x000007fefb048000     C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x000000006ad80000 - 0x000000006ad8d000     C:\Windows\system32\MFC100ENU.DLL
0x000007fef6ad0000 - 0x000007fef6ae8000     C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\bin\ntvocx.dll
0x000000006a7a0000 - 0x000000006a7cb000     C:\Windows\system32\ATL100.DLL
0x000007feff8c0000 - 0x000007feff959000     C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x000007fefccb0000 - 0x000007fefccc8000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc9b0000 - 0x000007fefc9f7000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefd400000 - 0x000007fefd414000     C:\Windows\system32\RpcRtRemote.dll
0x000007fefd360000 - 0x000007fefd3f1000     C:\Windows\system32\SXS.DLL
0x000007fef8920000 - 0x000007fef8a45000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -DJINTEGRA_NATIVE_MODE 
java_command: Code1
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Peter\workspace\HYSYSTry\src;C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\lib\jintegra.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
CLASSPATH=C:\Users\Peter\workspace\HYSYSTry\src;C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\lib\jintegra.jar
PATH=C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Users\Peter\jintegra6402\com6402\bin
USERNAME=Peter
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 , 64 bit Build 7601 (6.1.7601.23539)

CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

Memory: 4k page, physical 8348616k(3874056k free), swap 16695372k(10802908k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_101-b13), built on Jun 22 2016 01:21:29 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Mon Oct 03 13:46:06 2016
elapsed time: 2 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your post.  Are you asking how to debug the error?  If not, please be more specific.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes thats what Im asking about. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734587/failed-to-write-core-dump-minidumps-are-not-enabled-by-default-on-client-versio)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to follow the same procedure but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an access violation, it's likely caused by the "native" VB code. To get more information about the native side, use `-XX:+UseOSErrorReporting`. This will pass the exception to Windows, which can then do whatever it does when an application crashes.

By default, Windows will show the "Send error report to Microsoft", which is probably not what you want. Luckily there's the [`LocalDumps`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx) Registry key which can be configured to write the crash information to your disk instead. The executable name will be `java.exe` or `javaw.exe`.

Other than that, not that VB6 is no longer supported and VB6 has awful symbols. This might make your life hard analyzing the crash dump.

VB6 is heavily based on Microsoft COM. And Microsoft COM requires marshalling objects to the correct thread. This can go wrong in Java, since it's easily possible to have many threads there.

If you need to marshal COM interfaces to threads manually, Google for the GIT (global interface table) and the ROT (running object table). It probably requires you to write a small piece of C++ code that does it for you.